# how to turn on ssl for mydomain.azurewebsites.net?

Tags: azure, ssl

I have found instructions for enabling ssl on an azure service when I give it a custom domain, but if I just use the default *.azurewebsites.net, how do I turn on SSL for that?

Comment: a wildcard SSL certificate *.azurewebsites.net is already provided by Microsoft and, as Maarten mentioned, SSL / HTTPS is by default enabled. You do not need anything.

Answer (score 6):

No action needed. SSL is enabled by default for web app services under azurewebsites.net

Note: You'll need at least a Basic service plan. SSL is not available in the Free and Shared plan. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/